# Publisher / subscriber usage slipping into statefulness

Tags: c#

This is a general design question that I'm currently hung up on. It is causing a bit of a mental code block... I don't want to continue with it like this if it is simply a common pitfall, but I'd like to continue if it's accepted usage as the code is quite clean and decoupled (barring the cross-cutting messages).

I have a list-based publisher / subscriber pattern in code that I use to allow arbitrary sections of code to send messages that unknown subscribers can listen to. Fairly straightforward.

One of my current use cases for this pattern is to spin up a UI status indicator showing the user the application is busy. There is a message before work starts, a repeating message for progress, and a message for completion. It seems clean, the lower levels of code only publish messages and care not for listeners.

The starting message drives the UI initially; it shows a marquee progress bar in the status bar of the main form. The completion message hides this progress bar. Update messages are represented as text in a label.

Without realising at the time, I made the UI dependent on the order of these messages. The UI relies on the start and completion messages in order to reflect the UI correctly.  The "statefulness" I refer to is on the subscriber side (the messages themselves do not retain any state).

Is this usage going against the pub / sub pattern? If so, is the issue the reliance on message order? If not, then good, I can carry on :-)

Comment: doesn't sound horrid, get back to your code buddy! :)

Comment: What happens if the messages come out of order?

Comment: @cadrell0 It may not start or once shown may not close... The source of my questioning the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the [sequential coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling) code smell may be coming from your subscriber knowing too much about the inner workings of the publisher (i.e. When one starts, the other starts).

You can reduce the coupling by reducing the information in the message or by having the subscriber not take advantage of the temporal sequences of the messages.

For example, have the subscriber execute the same routine for the begin and in progress messages, reducing the resolution of the message to "WORKING." The UI subscriber can spawn the dialog if needed or update it if it already exists. It's the UI subscriber's job to manage the lifetime of the dialog box, not the application's.

However, this small smell is probably not enough to start convoluting the messages between the application and the UI subscriber.

Alternatively, you could make your subscriber robust enough to Do The Right Thing regardless of the sequence of messages that are called. Start, start, process, end, process, start, etc. The subscriber's responsibility should be managing the progress dialog box...to do the best it can no matter what crazy messages are coming from the application.

Comment: I agree on the code smell. I've come to the concluson that coupling the start / stop is the problem and will refactor this to be a UI concern.

Answer (score 1):

I share your "something doesn't seem right" feeling.

Should you be able to execute the publisher without a UI involved? I suspect so. The UI may start things going I suppose but the fact that you have it knowing the publisher inner workings - that the publisher is in a certain state "beginning", "middle", and "end" - is a code smell.

Perhaps the UI should just be another subscriber. The subscription "topic" (to use [pub/sub terminology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649664.aspx#despublishsubscribe_solution)) would be "processProgress" let's say and the publisher itself would send messages, inside the particular methods, reflecting that. OR [some other class that is controlling the execution](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMediator.aspx#_self1) of publisher would invoke publisher to send beginning/middle/ending messages.

Based on the message received, the UI would decide to display the progress bar and what message to display.

Comment: I agree on the code smell. I will decouple the lifetime of the dialog from the messages in terms of start and stop, instead driving that entirely from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is ok in general for a pub/sub pattern.
But do you have considered how to handle nested calls?

Assuming you have three calls on publisher:

- GetFirstName()
- GetLastName()
- GetFullName()

If I understood you you would throw the begin/inProgress/end messages in every call. If *GetFullName()* calls the both other calls internally to construct the full name the messages would be:
begin (full name) - begin (first name) - end (first name) - begin (last name) - end (last name) - end (full name).
So the progress bar flickers for the one GetFullName() call.

Do you considered that scenarios? Maybe you can use a counter, but then what is with exceptions which prevents calling of *end* messages...

Comment: The UI keeps a count of calls so on the last end call of a series of ends, it hides the status bar. This is actually an example of something I'm not sure about. That sort of dependency on the chain of messages is giving me cause to rethink. Currently to handle exceptions, the publisher of the messages ensures the end message is published via a try-finally or using block.

Comment: Try-finally sounds good. I would be happy if you inform us about your experience about that feature in case you implement it.

Comment: On reflection I think a reliance on the schema of the messages is more Message Bus than my current implementation, I've chosen to refactor out the dependency on the schema.